# I is trapped - Can you help?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

## Solve the encryption and get the passcode to open the vessel


[image: enter]
[image]
[image: description]
[image: here]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> If you rotate it just right, (down 1, down 6, down 3, down 6, no move, down 3, no move, down 5, no move, and down 7) you get something like 
>
>  
>  `PUZZLEYOUR
>  PASSWORDIS
>  THEMISSING
>  CHARACTERS
>  FROMALLTHE
>  ALPHABETGO
>  NOWANDTELL
>  OURFRIENDS
>  SPLENDIDLY
>  TOOPENTHIS
>  PUZZLEYOUR`
>  
>  
> showing up (one row repeated), which when cleaned up says  *YOUR PASSWORD IS THE MISSING CHARACTERS FROM ALL THE ALPHABET. GO NOW AND TELL OUR FRIENDS SPLENDIDLY TO OPEN THIS PUZZLE.*  
>  
>  The missing letters (and thus the answer) are **JKQVX**.

> And after all that, here's a picture from the OP of the vessel after you open it:
>
>  [image: hooray!]

Comment: @Rubio: The title refers to the answer, an "eye" (= "I") which is trapped in a vessel. And I believe the link is to give 3D model of the vessel itself, in case the series of screenshots from multiple angles is still ambiguous

Comment: @justhalf The comment you were answering was put there before the final answer was provided. The eye angle is now known. I've removed my earlier comment as it is no longer relevant.

Comment: Wait, I just realized that the image is not part of solving the puzzle, as it is given by OP. I thought the five letters corresponds to an Imgur link with that image. I guess this puzzle could have been made better.